# Linux C-programming / Terminal output to a C programm

Tags: redirect, store

I want  to redirect (store, or write) the output data from  terminal (Shell) to a string variable in my C program. The data are generated in the Linux terminal using the `cangen` command.

I can generate the CAN-Data and I want to use this data in my C-Programm.

can somebody help me please?

I use netbeans as IDE
Thank you

Comment: Probably off-topic here. Did you read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)? Maybe you want `MYVAR=$(cangen)`

Comment: Would `var=$(cangen)` work?